# Location Based Notifications are not calling in suspend mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager

I am new to location based applications. 
My requirement is, device has to show the location based notifications when the user reaches the selected region.
I implemented perfectly. This app is working on background also.
Now my new requirement is, device has to show the location based notifications even after kill the app. [I saw a couple of iPhone apps working with this functionality. The apps are "Reminder" & "Locationizer" ] .

Can you please check my implementations steps as follows.

- Launch the application.
- Selected the location alert button.
- Called the following CLLocationManager API's to monitor my region.

  [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:@"MyRegion" desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
  [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
- Quit the app [Running in background].
- I am getting location based alert notifications properly.

Here the new requirement.

- Launch the application.
- Selected the location alert Button.
- Called the following CLLocationManager API's to monitor my region.

  [locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:@"MyRegion" desiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
  [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
- Kill the app. [now application is not running in background]
- App should show the location based notification when user reach the location.

How do I implement this logic?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Friends I found solution for this issue.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

id locationValue = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey];
if (locationValue)
{
      [self initLocationMonitoring]; // this will invoke CLLocationManager
}

return YES;
}
```

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
 
 id locationValue = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey];
 if (locationValue)
 {
        
        [self initLocationMonitoring]; // this will invoke CLLocationManager
 }

 return YES;
}

Comment: Can you also provide your [self initLocationMonitoring]; here. I have done all that you have done but can't get a notification when app is killed!!!! :(

Answer (score 0):

An app that is quitted cant perform any functioning...so i will suggest to recheck those apps ..they must be functioning in the background to check the location of the device...they won't be able to alert if they are quitted.

Comment: is APNS [ Push notification] is solution for this ?

Comment: APNS..is a solution if you want to present a notification at a certain time... but to push notification based on device location ..can be done if only you send the location to the web service...which you can't since your app is quitted..it is possible if app is running in background

Comment: Yes you are correct , This is possible if app is running in background. But how do i through the notification if user kill the app.